# Disable submit button after validation jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have tried this:

```
$(".body-content form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        debugger;
        // do other things for a valid form
        $(":submit", form).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

But this just doesn't work, at all.

And this triggers before the validation. So if the form doesn't pass validation the submit button remains disabled.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC and jQuery for this.

Comment: why doesnt the first code work at all? have you used console.log to debug it? is the form submitted with the first code?

Comment: The first one does literally nothing. The debugger statement is never even hit.

Comment: This is done using the `submitHandler` callback function.  Refer to the jsFiddle demos in linked duplicate.